# gnome panel became ugly

Tags: gnome, themes, 17.10, gnome-panel

yesterday I did a fresh install with ubuntu 17.10.

Then I did some playing around with themes and extensions. Then I did a reboot and after the reboot the gnome-bar became very ugly.

It should look like this: [image]

(light transparency of the bar, calendar in center)

But instead it looks like this:

[image]

(No transparency, calendar at the right side, theme doesn't seem to apply)

**How do I get back the nice gnome panel from the first screenshot?**

---

additional notes:

After the reboot, that broke the bar, also a lot of extensions appeared. I couldn't remove them via extensions.gnome.org/local/, so I removed them via `rm -r`. For some reason those unwanted extensions come back, when I do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extensions`. I'd like to get rid of them permanently, but for now I'm fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in your terminal after going to your Home folder.

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

This will delete any changes that you have made permanently. Then log out and log back in to check if that worked.